# Does using a single trim function solve sql injection?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

Since the trim function removes the space, does it solve the problem for sql injection? If not, can someone post an example please.

Comment: Please google "SQL Injection example"

Comment: Why do you think that spaces are related to SQL injection?

Comment: Most definitely not. It only removes leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: I can't think of any witty answers for this.  Oh, wait...

Comment: @ChenErnest Could you give an example of how trimming *would* protect against SQL injection?

Answer (score 0):

No, adding a trim will not prevent sql injection. trim only removes space on the outside of your string.

```
Select * from aTable where name like '%'+@SearchString+'%'
```

If you @SearchString held something like

```
'' update aTable set someColumn='JackedUpValue' where someColumn like '
```

Then when you put it all together and execute it dynamically you would get

```
Select * from aTable where name like '%' update aTable set someColumn='JackedUpValue' where someColumn like '%'
```

You could trim on @SearchString 100 times, and not change its value at all.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid Sql Injection use the following:

1. Prepare Statements
2. Stored Procedures

your application will be pretty much safe.

For further detailed and expert analysis search google.
Here is a link to give you a start [Sql Injection Prevention](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)